# How to Create a 3 Column Join Table Between 2 Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activemodel, database-relations

I'm trying to create a join table between 2 models that has 3 columns. The models are called `User` and `Dare`. The join table is called `DaresUsers`. And what I want to include in the join table is an `author_id`, `accepter_id`, `dare_id`.

Each dare will only have one author but will have many `accepters` because more than one user can accept the same dare. Should I use a `has_many through` relationship and if so what would I declare in my models? My confusion here is because the `User` model is referenced by the join table in two respects: the `author_id` and `accepter_id`.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Dare < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :dare_user_relations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :accepters, through: :dare_user_relations
end

class DareUserRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :accepter, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :dare
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :dare, foreign_key: 'author_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :dare_user_relations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :dares, through: :dare_user_relations, foreign_key: 'accepter_id'
end
```

or w/o a model:

```
class Dare < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :accepters, class_name: 'User', association_foreign_key: 'accepter_id'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :dare, foreign_key: 'author_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :dares, foreign_key: 'accepter_id'
end
```

Comment: thanks for your response, the problem with this solution though is that now the `user` can only have one `dare`, when they should be able to have many `dares`. Also, the `user` should `has_and_belongs_to_many` `dares` with a `foreign_key: 'accepter_id'` correct?

Comment: @ddig, thanks for details, got your case. See the updated answer.

Comment: I think this works thank you very much, I just have one last question, I was under the impression that whenever you have two `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships between two models that a join table is always necessary. I'm referencing you're second solution, specifically the relationship between `accepters` and `dares`

Comment: Sure, you need a join table named dares_users. However, keep in mind that you don't need a model for this join table. Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: yes Sergey this helped me, I ended up creating a new model because I needed the join table to have multiple attribute columns, thank you very much!